# Git instaweb on windows? got a error

Tags: windows, git, instaweb

Is it possible to use **instaweb** on windows?

I have a bare repository at D:/myrepo and I want to use **instaweb** to see it like
[this](http://git-scm.com/figures/18333fig0401-tn.png)

I have tried this command

```
git instaweb --httpd=webrick
```

But I got this error

```
git: 'instaweb' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you installed it?

Comment: @DanielA.White installed what? git? I have git and I can clone/pull/push/...

Comment: i mean have you installed instaweb

Comment: I'm not sure, I read it should be installed with git. How can I know it? if not, How can I install it?

Comment: @DanielA.White  How can I know it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instaweb command is not yet supported for Windows as of version 1.9.0. It's listed under 'Known issues' in the Windows release notes:

> **Known issues**
>
> • Some commands are not yet supported on Windows and excluded from the
>   installation; namely: git archimport, git cvsexportcommit, git
>   cvsimport, git cvsserver, git instaweb, git shell.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working using git in MSYS2:

1. Install MSYS2
2. Install git:

   `pacman -S git`
3. Install ruby (webrick is part of Ruby standard library):

   `pacman -S ruby`
4. You may need to install the *CGI.pm* perl module using CPAN
5. And go:

   `git instaweb -d webrick`