# How to install GitWeb on Windows?

Tags: git, repository, gitweb, instaweb

I'm trying to use GitWeb to explore my repositories, I'm completely new to it, so I'm having a little problems, I know that GitWeb is shipped with Git, I downloaded it from here http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=full+installer+official+git, it is located on \share\gitweb, then I opened the console (Git Bash), browsed to the repository and ran the command `git instaweb`, but it says `git: 'instaweb' is not a git command`.

Anyone know what is the right way to install and configure GitWeb?

I already read a lot of tutorials, but they are so confusing :/

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this extension could help you :

https://github.com/alberthier/git-webui

It should work on Windows if you have Python installed

Answer (score 2):

`git instaweb` is not currently supported on windows by 'msysgit'.

See this [issue](https://github.com/msysgit/git/issues/11) which is still not resolved.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Gogs (mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46000425/6309)) is **[gitea.io](https://gitea.io)**.

Gogs is developed by one maintainer ([@Unknwon](https://github.com/Unknwon)).
Gitea is developed [more collaboratively](https://blog.gitea.io/2016/12/welcome-to-gitea/).

[Gitea releases](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/releases) are more regular than [Gogs releases](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/releases), and its [feature set](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/) is more complete.

[image: gitea]

Comment: +1 for Gitea. It is like a (small) github on your server. Allows to manage organizations, teams, pull requests, security.

Answer (score 1):

I tried different versions of "local github" and found the most beautiful solution in Windows for me:
Gogs https://gogs.io/ ([demo](https://try.gogs.io/))

Easy install - you need only Git Version >= 1.7.1 for both server and client sides. And it allows do pull requests!

Just to give an idea how it looks like in the browser:

[image]

Comment: Just confirming that I've been through same tears and pain and as of now (2018-04-18) **Gogs** is the best (if not only) viable and reliable solution for locally hosted git repo on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

As in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57177967/2284995):

> I got it working using git in MSYS2:
>
> 1. Install MSYS2
> 2. Install git:
>
>    `pacman -S git`
> 3. Install ruby (webrick is part of Ruby standard library):
>
>    `pacman -S ruby`
> 4. You may need to install the *CGI.pm* perl module using CPAN
> 5. And go:
>
>    `git instaweb -d webrick`

Answer (score 0):

[Gitwin](http://www.itefix.net/gitwin) supports Gitweb in FastCGI mode via a built-in Nginx server.

NB! Disclaimer - product edition only.

Answer (score 0):

4 years later (2018), `gitweb` is definitively removed from Git for Windows:

See [Git for Windows 2.19.0](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.19.0.windows.1) (Sept. 2018):

> The `gitweb` component was removed because it is highly unlikely to be used on Windows.

See [git-for-windows/git issue 1362](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1362)

> Git for Windows is intended to be used by end users. GitWeb, however, wants to be used in conjunction with a web server such as Apache, and even requires a Perl module to be installed in that web server.
>
> It is almost guaranteed that nobody uses Git for Windows that way, so let's just exclude those files from the installer.